# How to insert image directly from URL in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do this:

```
= image_tag("images/no-photo.jpg")
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
 <img alt="No-photo" src="/assets/images/no-photo.jpg" />
```

And it shows only Alt text, not a picture, though picture is there.

When I go to the link in HTML code browser I see that it gives a routing error (no route matches GET /assets/images/no-photo.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture is where? In public/images/no-photo.jpg?  Or in app/assets/images/no-photo.jpg? Or?

If you want to reference a full/absolute url for image_tag do it like this:

```
= image_tag("/images/no-photo.jpg")
```

The leading slash tells it not to mess with it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be.  You can use the asset pipeline, but then you'd want to put the file in app/assets/images/no-photo.jpg and link to it without the leading slash.

Answer (score 1):

```
%img{:src => asset_path("example.jpg")}/
```